# Get settings object from build.gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

How can I get settings object programmatically inside build.gradle file?
I tried `Settings.settings` but gradle shows me

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':social_lib'.
> No such property: settings for class: org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings
  Possible solutions: settings, settingsDir
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make multipojects with modules inside. I do not want mention these modules inside main project because project depends only from subproject. Subproject depends from module.